# How can I combine child nodes with JSX?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to build up a ul list from li elements, but the li elements will come from different sources, so I can't do it in one statement. It appears that JSX can't handle a set of child elements, this gives me a syntax error:

```
var items = <li>S</li>
  <li>S</li>
  <li>S</li>;
```

Ideally I want to do something like:

```
var items1 = <li>S</li>
  <li>S</li>
  <li>S</li>;
var items2 = <li>S</li>
  <li>S</li>
  <li>S</li>;
var list = <ul>{items1}{items2}</ul>;
```

Is there another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

JSX desugars very straightforwardly to Javascript syntax so you can mix it freely.

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */
var items1 = [ <li>S</li>,            var items1 = [ React.DOM.li({}, "S"),
               <li>S</li>,                           React.DOM.li({}, "S"),
               <li>S</li> ];                         React.DOM.li({}, "S") ];
var items2 = [ <li>S</li>,            var items2 = [ React.DOM.li({}, "S"),
               <li>S</li>,                           React.DOM.li({}, "S"),
               <li>S</li> ];                         React.DOM.li({}, "S") ];
var list = <ul>{items1+items2}</ul>;  var list = React.DOM.ul({}, items1+items2);
```

Comment: The subtle point that was contributing to my syntax error is that I did not have a comma between the <li> elements.

Comment: As pointed out, it's definitely worth looking at the desugared output to get a good idea of what's happening. It's mostly straightforward but not everything is obvious.

http://facebook.github.io/react/jsx-compiler.html might be helpful for quick checking!

Comment: You can't concatenate arrays with `+`.